# Is there's any guarantee that AWS SQS FIFO msgs with different messageGroupId will not stay unprocessed for long time?

Tags: amazon-web-services

**The Problem:** 
If I added all my messages with the same MessageGroupId, then if I have multiple processors each can process 10 msgs, I will not be able to process more than 10 msgs concurrently, so in fact a single processor will always work and the others will receive nothing.

**Solution I Tried:**
Simply adding different MessageGroupId for each msg.

**Question:**
Is there's any guarantee that in case of spike in new msgs - more than all the processors can handle - that the processors might keep processing new msgs and abandon old ones simply because they have different MessageGroupId? or old msgs will have priority for delivery?

Comment: you can use a single processor and make it threaded and you can process each message in the thread.
About using different messageGroupId you will have to have a fixed number of groups and round robin on the new message to assign a group id. I believe its a fifo queue, so the old msg will have priority over the new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no affinity between individual consumers and MessageGroupId.

MessageGroupId is essentially a semaphore that says, for each group, "if any message with this MessageGroupId is in flight, and another consumer is waiting for messages, always give the other consumer a message with a different MessageGroupId, else give them nothing at all, even if there is a message with MessageGroupId that could be visible to consumers," because when a group has a message in flight, the remaining messages in that same group are temporarily locked.

It assures that messages within each MessageGroupId are never processed out-of-sequence.

If the ordering of two messages relative to each other is important, they need to have the same MessageGroupId.  If all of your messages in the entire queue must be processed in strict order, then it doesn't make sense to have more than one consumer, anyway, because multiple consumers can't process messages in strict order... sort of by definition.

If your messages in queue have different MessageGroupIds, a given consumer will not stick with a single MessageGroupId between requests.  After finishing a batch it should next receive the oldest message from the group that has the oldest visible message and that has no messages in flight, and up to 9 additional messages.  If the first group has fewer than 10 messages remaining, you may receive messages from other groups, as well, in the set of 10.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the context. I would highlight also this statement which is the direct answer "After finishing a batch it should next receive the oldest message from the group that has the oldest visible message and that has no messages in flight"